# Unable to Add More than One Cstring to an array of Cstrings

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have this function for adding an event (each event being a cstring) to an array of events:

```
bool vendor::addEvent(const char * event)
{
    if (eventsSize == EVENTS_CAP - 1)
        return false;
    eventsSize++; //keep track of the size of the array
    this->events = new char*[EVENTS_CAP]; //outer array
    this->events[eventsSize-1] = new char[strlen(event) + 1]; //cstring array
    strcpy(this->events[eventsSize-1], event);
    return true;
}
```

`EVENTS_CAP` is equal to 20 and is part of my vendor class, along with eventsSize and events (which you will see in the following images). This function works fine after passing in one event: [image]

But passing in another event renders the array unreadable:[image]

Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: is there any good reason why you use chars and c-style arrays ? Just asking, because its much easier to tell you "Use std::string and std::vector" rather than fixing this mess

Comment: BTW, you can be more productive by not using the `this->` syntax.  It is not needed in C++ (except when parameter and member have the same name).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews many IDEs have autocompletion and then it can be much fast to only type `this->` and using autocomplete instead of typing the full member name

Comment: C++ has changed *a lot* since, say, C++ from 20+ years ago, which is what that code resembles. Here: `vector<string> events; ... bool vendor::addEvent(const char* event) { events.push_back(event); }`  One line of code replaces all of what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reallocating the `events` array (and leaking the old one) every time you call the `addEvent()` function.

Because you increment `eventsSize` you write to the next array member each time through, and the previous ones are left uninitialized (which explains why it looks like the array contains garbage on the second pass).

You probably just need to make the following change:

```
if (!this->events) this->events = new char*[EVENTS_CAP]; //outer array
```

Comment: As is usually the case, I feel like an idiot for not seeing that. Thank you! I wasn't sure who had the best answer, so I just marked yours as correct because you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to comment or I would.

That said, it would be helpful if we knew exactly what you have "events" defined as.  From the information that we do I have I'd imagine that

```
this->events = new char*[EVENTS_CAP]; //outer array
this->events[eventsSize-1] = new char[strlen(event) + 1]; //cstring array
```

The first line is a memory leak.  You are redefining where events points every time.

On the second line if (eventsSize - 1) > EVENTS_CAP you are going to clobber something.

Since this is tagged C++ I would suggest using std::vector and std::string and simply have a std::vector.